# Count the words in a text and display them

Tags: code-golf

The code should take input a text (not mandatory can be anything file, stdin, string for JavaScript, etc):

```
This is a text and a number: 31.
```

The output should contain the words with their number of occurrence, sorted by the number of occurrences in descending order:

```
a:2
and:1
is:1
number:1
This:1
text:1
31:1
```

Notice that 31 is a word, so a word is anything alpha-numeric, number are not acting as separators so for example `0xAF` qualifies as a word. Separators will be anything that is not alpha-numeric including `.`(dot) and `-`(hyphen) thus `i.e.` or `pick-me-up` would result in 2 respectively 3 words. Should be case sensitive, `This` and `this` would be two different words,  `'` would also be separator so `wouldn`and `t` will be 2 different words from `wouldn't`.

Write the shortest code in your language of choice.

Shortest correct answer so far:

- **[grep and coreutils - 42 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19572/12328)**

Comment: Does case matter (ie is `This` the same as `this` and `tHIs`)?

Comment: If anything non-alphanumeric counts as a separator, is `wouldn't` 2 words (`wouldn` and `t`)?

Comment: @Gareth Should be case sensitive, `This` and `this` would be indeed two different words,  same `wouldn`and `t`.

Comment: If Wouldn't are 2 words, shouldn't it be "Would" and "nt" since its short for Would not, or is that to much grammer nazi-ish?

Comment: @TeunPronk I try to keep it simple, putting a few rules will encourage exceptions to be in order with grammar , and there are a lot of exceptions out there.Ex in English `i.e.` is a word but if we let the dot all the dots at the end of phrases will be taken, same with quotes or single quotes, etc.

Comment: Should words that have the same count be sorted by ascending alpha? or by some other sort?

Comment: @KevinFegan That is not one of requirements.

Comment: Is the formatting of the output important - i.e. do you have to output word:count - or are other formats ok, e.g. (word, count)?

Comment: Vaguely realted old questions from Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169051/code-golf-word-frequency-chart/

Comment: Is `*&%@!#!` a word ? 
(I assume no , since they would all be counted as seperators)

Comment: @TejasKale you are right  `*&%@!#!` for that reason is not a word.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### grep and coreutils  <s>44</s>  42

```
grep -io '[a-z0-9]*'|sort|uniq -c|sort -nr
```

Test:

```
printf "This is a text and a number: 31." |
grep -io '[a-z0-9]*'|sort|uniq -c|sort -nr
```

Results in:

```
  2 a
  1 This
  1 text
  1 number
  1 is
  1 and
  1 31
```

#### Update

- Use case-insensitive option and shorter regex. Thanks Tomas.

Comment: This being almost exactly McEllroy's response to Knuth's book _Literate Programming_. The only difference being that this does not include a pipe into `head` at the end.

Comment: This was pretty much my first thought too.

Comment: Wouldn't '\w+' work as well?

Comment: @Sylwester: The `\w` character group consists of `[:alnum:]` and `_`, which, I think, has the same status as the hyphen.

Comment: +1 Pretty straightforward, exactly what I was about to write :)

Comment: **41 characters**: `grep -io \[A-Z0-9]*|sort|uniq -c|sort -nr`

Comment: @Tomas: Added this to the answer, thanks. I left in protection for the asterisk, because it was expanding file names in some shells.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `-o \[a-Z0-9]*`

Answer (score 18):

## Java 8: 289

Which is pretty good, since java is a very non-golfy language.

```java
import java.util.stream.*;class C{static void main(String[]a){Stream.of(a).flatMap(s->of(s.split("[\\W_]+"))).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x->x,Collectors.counting())).entrySet().stream().sorted(x,y->x.getValue()-y.getValue()).forEach(e->System.out.println(e.getKey()+":"+e.getValue()));}
```

Ungolfed:

```java
import java.util.stream.*;
class C {
    static void main(String [] args){
        Stream.of(args).flatMap(arg->Stream.of(arg.split("[\\W_]+")))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(word->word,Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet().stream().sorted(x,y->x.getValue()-y.getValue())
            .forEach(entry->System.out.println(entry.getKey()+":"+entry.getValue()));
    }
}
```

Run from the command line:

```
java -jar wordCounter.jar This is a text and a number: 31.
```

Comment: Wrong regex for splitting. It should be `"[^\\W_]"`

Comment: @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳, the `String.split(String regex)` method takes a pattern that matches the _delimiter_ to split on. So, for instance, `"aababba".split("b")` would yield the array `{"aa", "a", "", "a"}`. My regex `[^\\w\\d]` means 'a character in neither the word character nor digit character classes'. `[^\\W_]` is instead 'a character that is neither an underscore nor is in the non-word-character class' and would match any word character except the underscore.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was incorrect. `\w` includes `\d`, so `\d` is redundant. `\w` includes underscore, which should be considered a separator according to the question. So the correct regex for splitting should be `"[\\W_]+"`.

Comment: @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳ ok, thanks; I've fixed the problem.

Answer (score 17):

### APL (57)

```
⎕ML←3⋄G[⍒,1↓⍉G←⊃∪↓Z,⍪+⌿∘.≡⍨Z←I⊂⍨(I←⍞)∊⎕D,⎕A,⎕UCS 96+⍳26;]
```

e.g.

```
      ⎕ML←3⋄G[⍒,1↓⍉G←⊃∪↓Z,⍪+⌿∘.≡⍨Z←I⊂⍨(I←⍞)∊⎕D,⎕A,⎕UCS 96+⍳26;]
This is a text and a number: 31.
 a       2
 This    1
 is      1
 text    1
 and     1
 number  1
 31      1
```

Explanation:

- `⎕D,⎕A,⎕UCS 96+⍳26`: numbers, uppercase letters, lowercase letters
- `(I←⍞)∊`: read input, store in `I`, see which ones are alphanumeric
- `Z←I⊂⍨`: split `I` in groups of alphanumeric characters, store in `Z`
- `+⌿∘.≡⍨Z`: for each element in `Z`, see how often it occurs
- `Z,⍪`: match each element in `Z` pairwise with how many times it occurs
- `G←⊃∪↓`: select only the unique pairs, store in `G`
- `⍒,1↓⍉G`: get sorted indices for the occurrences
- `G[`...`;]`: reorder the lines of `G` by the given indices

Comment: what... the... f.....

Comment: This is why I have nightmares.

Comment: @Thebluefish: APL was designed from a notation, with the intention that much like maths, a concise notation frees you to think clearly. Again like maths, when you first see that notation, you tend to think it's not clear at all, but languages always seem complex to begin with. It would be easier if it wasn't all on one line, though...

Comment: whatever you come up with in APL I only see some unicode garbage, arrows pointing in directions and an upside down pine tree. that is worse than J

Comment: Could be shorter with `⎕s` (http://help.dyalog.com/latest/Content/Language/System%20Functions/r.htm) and the new key operator (http://help.dyalog.com/latest/Content/Language/Primitive%20Operators/Key.htm):
`g⌷⍨⊂⍒2⌷⍉g←{⍺,≢⍵}⌸('\w+'⎕s'\0')⍞`

Answer (score 8):

## C#: <s>153c</s> <s>144c</s> <s>142c</s> <s>111c</s> <s>115c</s> <s>118c</s> <s>114c</s> 113c

*(via LINQPad in "C# Statements" mode, not including input string)*

### Version 1: 142c

```
var s = "This is a text and a number: 31."; // <- line not included in count
s.Split(s.Where(c=>!Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)).ToArray(),(StringSplitOptions)1).GroupBy(x=>x,(k,e)=>new{s,c=e.Count()}).OrderBy(x=>-x.c).Dump();
```

Ungolfed:

```
var s = "This is a text and a number: 31.";
s.Split(                                                     // split string on multiple separators
    s.Where(c => !Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))                   // get list of non-alphanumeric characters in string
     .ToArray(),                                             // (would love to get rid of this but needed to match the correct Split signature)
    (StringSplitOptions)1                                    // integer equivalent of StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
).GroupBy(x => x, (k, e) => new{ s = k, c = e.Count() })     // count by word
 .OrderBy(x => -x.c)                                         // order ascending by negative count (i.e. OrderByDescending)
 .Dump();                                                    // output to LINQPad results panel
```

Results:

[image: Results]

### Version 2: 114c

(`[\w]` includes `_`, which is incorrect!; `[A-z]` includes `` [ \ ] ^ _ ` ``; settling on `[^_\W]+`)

```
var s = "This is a text and a number: 31."; // <- line not included in count
Regex.Matches(s, @"[^_\W]+").Cast<Match>().GroupBy(m=>m.Value,(m,e)=>new{m,c=e.Count()}).OrderBy(g=>-g.c).Dump();
```

Ungolfed:

```
Regex.Matches(s, @"[^_\W]+")                                   // get all matches for one-or-more alphanumeric characters
     .Cast<Match>()                                            // why weren't .NET 1 collections retrofitted with IEnumerable<T>??
     .GroupBy(m => m.Value, (m,e) => new{ m, c = e.Count() })  // count by word
     .OrderBy(g => -g.c)                                       // order ascending by negative count (i.e. OrderByDescending)
     .Dump();                                                  // output to LINQPad results panel
```

Results:
(as Version 1)

Comment: By the way, for version 2, your ungolfed version does not match your golfed version. And since you are using literal string, you can write `@"[^_\W]"`

Comment: @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳ - fixed the typo and removed the extra `\` for a 1-char saving -- thanks!!

Answer (score 7):

#### R, 58 char

```
sort(table(unlist(strsplit(scan(,""),"[[:punct:]]"))),d=T)
```

Usage:

```
sort(table(unlist(strsplit(scan(,""),"[[:punct:]]"))),d=T)
1: This is a text and a number: 31.
9: 
Read 8 items

     a     31    and     is number   text   This 
     2      1      1      1      1      1      1
```

Comment: This is shorter (49 chars) `sort(table(gsub("[[:punct:]]","",scan(,""))),d=T)`. Unfortunately both solutions doesn't work correctly for `wouldn't`.

Answer (score 6):

## Python <s>101</s> 97

```
import re
a=re.split('[_\W]+',input())
f=a.count
for w in sorted(set(a),key=f)[::-1]:print w,f(w)
```

Now works with newline:

```
$ python countword.py <<< '"This is    a text and a number: 31, and a\nnewline"'
a 3
and 2
31 1
number 1
newline 1
is 1
text 1
This 1
```

Comment: This doesn't work when there are newlines or more than one consecutive space in text.

Comment: @klingt.net fixed.

Answer (score 6):

### PHP - 84 bytes

```
<?$a=array_count_values(preg_split('/[_\W]+/',$argv[1],0,1));arsort($a);print_r($a);
```

Input is accepted as a command line argument, e.g.:

```
$ php count-words.php "This is a text and a number: 31."
```

Output for the sample string:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 2
    [number] => 1
    [31] => 1
    [and] => 1
    [text] => 1
    [is] => 1
    [This] => 1
)
```

Comment: it says input is what you want. so you can get it as command line parameter using `$argv[1]`

Comment: @Einacio good call.

Comment: -1. Underscore `_` should not be included in a word.

Comment: @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳ fixed.

Answer (score 6):

### perl6: 49 characters

```
.say for get.comb(/\w+/).Bag.pairs.sort(-*.value)
```

Comb input for stuff matching `\w+`, put resulting list of words in a `Bag`, ask for their pairs and sort them by negative value. (The `*` is a [Whatever](http://perlcabal.org/syn/S02.html#The_Whatever_Object) star, it's not multiplication here)

output:

```
"a" => 2
"This" => 1
"is" => 1
"text" => 1
"and" => 1
"number" => 1
"31" => 1
```

Comment: Perl 6 scares me.

Comment: Every time I think of a cool language feature, I look for it and it's in Perl6 somewhere. That's why it's taking a long time...

Comment: You can trim 6 characters by using `.words` instead of `.comb(/\w+/)` :)

Comment: @Mouq: unfortunately `.words` doesn't strip the `:` or `.` from the input as required :(

Comment: -1. `_` should not be included in a word under the problem statement.

Answer (score 5):

**PowerShell (40)**

```
$s -split"\W+"|group -ca|sort count -des
```

$s is a variable that contains the input string.

Comment: `[\W]` isn't good enough - it is matching a space in my test.  And it is not ordered by descending count...

Comment: `$s -split"[\W]"|group -ca|where{$_.Name -ne ""}|sort{-$_.Count}` gets you closer (with costs, of course)

Comment: Ooops I missed the sorting part.  Will fix my answer shortly.

Comment: alternatively:
`$s -split"\W+"|group -ca |sort count -des`

Comment: `-split"\W+"` is matching an empty string between the last `.` and the end of the string; also `\W+` matches `_` which is technically not allowed

Answer (score 5):

## GNU awk + coreutils: <strike>71</strike> 69

```
gawk 'BEGIN{RS="\\W+"}{c[$0]++}END{for(w in c)print c[w],w}'|sort -nr
```

Although `gawk asort` works on associative arrays, it apparently does not preserve the index values, necessitating the external `sort`

```
printf "This is a text and a number: 31." | 
gawk 'BEGIN{RS="\\W+"}{c[$0]++}END{for(w in c)print c[w],w}'|sort -nr
2 a
1 This
1 text
1 number
1 is
1 and
1 31
```

## GNU awk 4.x: <strike>100</strike> 93

A slightly larger but pure gawk solution using `PROCINFO` to set the default sort order for the associative array (appears to require a relatively recent gawk - > 4.x?)

```
BEGIN{RS="\\W+";PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"}
{c[$0]++}
END{for(w in c)print c[w],w}
```

Comment: Oooooh. I didn't know about PROCINFO. As if I needed another excuse to use awk in my life. Curse you!

Comment: @dmckee TBH I didn't know about PROCINFO until I started poking around - I was convinced there _had_ to be a way to do the sort natively - just a pity the identifiers are so long ;)

Comment: In the bad old days there simply wasn't a way. Which leads to things like [this old answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3169562/2509).

Comment: -1. Underscore `_` should not be included in a word.

Answer (score 4):

### Perl 69

```pl
$h{$_}++for<>=~/\w+/g;print"$_: $h{$_}
"for sort{$h{$b}-$h{$a}}keys%h
```

Added recommendations from @primo and @protist

Comment: What about sorting?

Comment: @daniero, excellent point! This now sorts!

Comment: I think that's about as terse as it can get. If you don't mind a deprecation warning, no space is required between `ge` and `for`. Also, the `<=>` operator can be replaced by `-`.

Comment: @primo Ahhh `-` instead of `<=>` is genius, not sure that's on the golfing tips for Perl thread. I'll update this later, thanks!

Comment: you forgot digits...i wrote `$h{$_}++for<>=~m/\w++|\d++/g;print"$_:$h{$_}\n"for sort{$h{$a}>=$h{$b}}keys%h` then started looking around...then decided it was too similar to bear repeating :)...i like the sorting method in yours

Comment: Hey @protist, `\w` includes numbers too (`perl -e 'print for"a 1 2 3 4 b"=~/\w/g'` prints `a1234b`), but your mechanism for iterating the words saves another character so I'll update. Thank you!

Comment: -1. Underscore `_` should not be included in a word.

Answer (score 4):

### Powershell: <s>57</s> <s>55</s> <s>53</s> <s>62</s> 57

*(not including input string)*

```
$s = "This is a text and a number: 31."    # <-- not counting this line...
[Regex]::Matches($s,"[^_\W]+")|group -ca|sort{-$_.Count}
```

returns:

```
Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    2 a                         {a, a}
    1 and                       {and}
    1 31                        {31}
    1 number                    {number}
    1 This                      {This}
    1 is                        {is}
    1 text                      {text}
```

(with props to @microbian for group -ca)

Answer (score 3):

## Groovy <strike>77</strike> 82

changed regex from `[^\w]+` to `[^\d\p{L}]+` in order to solve problem with underscore

```
String s = 'This is a text and a number: 31'

def a=s.split(/[^\d\p{L}]+/) 
a.collectEntries{[it, a.count(it)]}.sort{-it.value}
```

without first line, 82 characters

output:

```
[a:2, This:1, is:1, text:1, and:1, number:1, 31:1]
```

Comment: `nu_ber` is not alphanumeric. This shouls be 2 words

Comment: Why use **`nu_ber`** instead of **`number`**?

Comment: I was mislead by some other posts ;) now I removed the "_" from the input, but fixed the regex to handle it

Answer (score 3):

## EcmaScript 6

### Version 1 (108 characters)

```
s.split(_=/[^a-z\d]/i).map(x=>_[x]=-~_[x]);keys(_).sort((a,b)=>_[a]<_[b]).map(x=>x&&console.log(x+':'+_[x]))
```

### Version 2 (102 characters)

```
s.split(_=/[^a-z\d]/i).map(x=>_[x]=-~_[x]);keys(_).sort((a,b)=>_[a]<_[b]).map(x=>x&&alert(x+':'+_[x]))
```

### Version 3 (105 characters)

```
s.match(_=/\w+/g).map(x=>_[x]=-~_[x]);alert(keys(_).sort((a,b)=>_[a]<_[b]).map(x=>x+':'+_[x]).join('\n'))
```

### Version 4 (94 characters)

```
s.match(_=/\w+/g).map(x=>_[x]=-~_[x]);keys(_).sort((a,b)=>_[a]<_[b]).map(x=>alert(x+':'+_[x]))
```

### Version 5 (without alert; 87 characters)

```
s.match(_=/\w+/g).map(x=>_[x]=-~_[x]);keys(_).sort((a,b)=>_[a]<_[b]).map(x=>x+':'+_[x])
```

### Version 6 (100 characters)

```
keys(_,s.match(_=/\w+/g).map(x=>_[x]=-~_[x])).sort((a,b)=>_[a]<_[b]).map(x=>console.log(x+':'+_[x]))
```

---

### Output:

```
a:2
31:1
This:1
is:1
text:1
and:1
number:1
```

Comment: You can change `_[a]` and `_[b]` to `_.a` and `_.b`. Also changing `/\w+/g,_={}` to `_=/\w+/g` will produce the same result.

Comment: @eithedog Thank you! However, I can't change `_[a]` to be `_.a` because it tries to access the property `"a"` of `_`, not the property `a`.

Comment: ah, correct - the order won't be kept. Carry on :)

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice your answer.. nice. But.. is `Object.keys` becoming a global in ES6? Your answer seems to assume this, but I don't recall seeing that as scheduled for ES6.

Comment: @FireFly I can't find any documentation, but it works fine in Firefox. I haven't tested it in Chrome/Opera/IE.

Comment: Underscore `_` should not be included in a word. Version 3-6 violates this rule.

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript - <s>132</s> 126 chars !

#### (Shortest JS code)

```
o={},a=[]
for(i in s=s.split(/[\W_]+/))o[z=s[i]]=o[z]+1||1
for(j in o)a.push([j,o[j]])
a.sort(function(b,c){return c[1]-b[1]})
```

Improved the regex and some edits.

---

### Ungolfed

```
s = s.split(/[\W_]+/), o={}, a=[]; // split along non-char letters, declare object and array

for (i in s) { n = s[i]; o[n] = o[n] + 1 || 1 } // go through each char and store it's occurence

for (j in o) a.push( [j, o[j]] ); // store in array for sorting

a.sort(function (b, c){ return c[1] - b[1]; }); // sort !
```

---

> <= // make s = "How shiny is this day is isn't is"
>
> => 
>       [ [ 'is', 3 ],
>         [ 'How', 1 ],
>         [ 'shiny', 1 ],
>         [ 'this', 1 ],
>         [ 'day', 1 ],
>         [ 'isn', 1 ],
>         [ 't', 1 ] ]

---

#### Old - <s>156</s> <s>143</s> <s>141</s> <s>140</s> 132 chars

```
s=s.split(/[^\w]+/g),o={}
for(i in s){n=s[i];o[n]=o[n]+1||1}a=[]
for(j in o)a.push([j,o[j]])
a.sort(function(b,c){return c[1]-b[1]})
```

---

Gave a first try at golfing. Feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby <s>58</s> <s>82</s> 65

```
h=Hash.new 0
gets.scan(/[\d\w]+/){h[$&]+=1}
p *h.sort_by{|k,v|-v}
```

Test run:

```
$ ruby counttext.rb <<< "This is a text and a number: 31."
["a", 2]
["text", 1]
["This", 1]
["is", 1]
["and", 1]
["number", 1]
["31", 1]
```

---

<sup>Edit 58->80: Ok, I was way off. I forgot to sort the words by occurrences. Also, `Array#uniq` is not an enumerator, but uses a given block to compare elements, so passing `puts` to it didn't filter out duplicates (not that it says that we should).</sup>

Comment: Maybe `split(/\W+/)` instead of `scan` (untested)?

Comment: @Howard Thanks. `\W` excludes `_` so that had to be fixed, but it still saved 2 characters (then I added 20 to fix the sorting that I had neglected).

Comment: Shouldn't be sorted in `reverse` `(a=gets.split(/[_\W]+/)).uniq.map{|w|[w,a.count(w)]}.sort_by(&:last).reverse.map{|x|p x}`

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu Nah. `reverse` is way too verbose ;) Btw, it's not fair changing the question.

Comment: If you see in the output sample it was sorted descended only that I forgot to specify it.

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu Yea, that was a sample! Could've been completely random that the output was like that ;)

Comment: @danier No, could not, not if sorted, I mentioned sorted but not descending, but if you see 2 first, and 1 second, and is sorted it cannot be random it descending.

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu Unless one uses a sorting function that randomizes the direction before it starts :D Ok, that's a stretch, but you never know...

Answer (score 2):

### Python - 95 ( now  ***87***  thanks to @primo)

```
d=__import__('re').findall(r'\w+',raw_input())
print sorted(map(lambda y:(y,d.count(y)),d))
```

Sample input :

```
'This is a text and a number: 31'
```

Sample output :

```
[('This', 1),('is', 1), ('a', 2),('text', 1),('and', 1),('a', 2),('number', 1),('31', 1)]
```

Any improvement sugestion would be appreciated

Comment: The solution is nice but the output is not sorted.

Comment: What do you mean by sorted? Thanks for the comment.

Comment: `\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Your entire regex can be replaced by `r'\w+'`. Also, the `x` variable is not needed, just use `raw_input()` as the second parameter to `findall`.

Comment: By sorted, the OP means that the words that appear most often need to be listed first. Also, your program should include a `print` statement (i.e. `print map(...`), otherwise it's not a complete program.

Comment: I don't have time to sort it right now :( I'm in a hurry , thanks for the suggestions and comments.

Comment: I suggest using `sorted`, and then reversing with `[::-1]`. I really want to +1 this, because I've never seen `__import__()` before.

Comment: Can someone explain to me or provide good tutorials and documentation of the sorted function? I have never used it before.

Comment: @Azwr try starting here: [Python built-in functions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html). You'll likely need to switch the order of `y` and `d.count(y)` to get it to sort by occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript <strike>160</strike> 144 (Edited: to meet requirements)

```
f=Function;o={};s.replace(/\w+/g,f('a','o[a]=++o[a]||1'));Object.keys(o).sort(f('b,c','return o[c]-o[b]')).map(f('k','console.log(k+" "+o[k])'))
```

Unminified:

```
f=Function;
o = {};
s.replace(/\w+/g, f('a','o[a]=++o[a]||1'));
Object.keys(o).sort(f('b,c', 'return o[c]-o[b]')).map(f('k','console.log(k+" "+o[k])'))
```

Logs each word to console in order, passing the following string:

`s="This is sam}}ple text 31to test the effectiveness of this code, you can clearly see that this is working-as-intended, but you didn't doubt it did you?.";`

Outputs:

```
you 3
this 2
is 2
can 1
text 1
31to 1
test 1
the 1
effectiveness 1
of 1
This 1
code 1
sam 1
ple 1
clearly 1
see 1
that 1
working 1
as 1
intended 1
but 1
didn 1
t 1
doubt 1
it 1
did 1
```

I don't have the heart to use `alert()`.

Comment: The sort should be by the number. of occurrences so `you` should be first.

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu Silly me... I'll fix it later.

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu fixed

Comment: -1. Underscore `_` should not be included in a word.

Comment: `++o[a]||1` => `-~o[a]`

Comment: Merge `f` and `o`

Answer (score 2):

### EcmaScript 6, <strike>115</strike> <strike>100</strike> 87 (without prompt&alert)

Thanks to @eithedog:

```
s.match(/\w+/g,a={}).map(w=>a[w]=-~a[w]),keys(a).map(w=>[w,a[w]]).sort((a,b)=>b[1]-a[1])
```

With prompt and alert (100):

```
prompt(a={}).match(/\w+/g).map(w=>a[w]=-~a[w]);alert(keys(a).map(w=>[w,a[w]]).sort((a,b)=>b[1]-a[1]))
```

Run it in Firefox.

Comment: You don't need `var `. Also, you can move `a={}` inside `prompt` - `prompt(a={})`. You can also drop `Object.` and change `w=>a[w]=a[w]+1||1` to `w=>a[w]=-~a[w]`

Comment: Very nice. Beats the working Python one now :)

Comment: Same as for @toothbrush's answer - moving the declaration of `a` from prompt to regexp will spare two more chars.

Comment: It's nice and clean. Good job!

Comment: -1. Underscore `_` should not be included in a word.

Answer (score 2):

**F# - 169**

```
let f s=(s+"").Split(set s-set(['a'..'z']@['A'..'Z']@['0'..'9'])|>Set.toArray)|>Seq.where((<>)"")|>Seq.countBy id|>Seq.sortBy((~-)<<snd)|>Seq.iter((<||)(printfn"%s:%d"))
```

Degolfed:

```
let count (s : string) =
    s.Split (set s - set (['a'..'z']@['A'..'Z']@['0'..'9']) |> Set.toArray)
 |> Seq.where ((<>) "")
 |> Seq.countBy id
 |> Seq.sortBy ((~-) << snd)
 |> Seq.iter ((<||) (printfn "%s:%d"))
```

Output when called from fsi:

```
> "This is a text and a number: 31." |> f
a:2
This:1
is:1
text:1
and:1
number:1
31:1
val it : unit = ()
```

**Update:** Some explanation as requested in the comments.

Uses set functions to generate an array of non alphanumeric characters in the input to pass to String.Split, then uses sequence functions to filter out empty strings, generate word counts and print the result.

Some golfing tricks: Adds an empty string to the function argument s to force type inference of the argument as a string rather than explicitly declaring the type. Uses Seq.where rather than Seq.filter to save a few characters (they are synonyms). Mixes forward pipe and ordinary function application in an attempt to minimize characters. Uses currying and (op) syntax to treat <> ~- and <|| operators as regular functions to avoid declaring lambdas to filter empty strings, sort by descending count and print tuples.

Comment: You should definitely insert some sort of explanation; that way we can understand your code.

Comment: Added a degolfed version and some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

## Pure Bash (no external programs), 164

This is longer than I'd hoped, but I wanted to see if the necessary counting and sorting (in the right direction) could be done purely with `bash` arrays (associative and non-associative):

```
declare -A c
for w in ${@//[[:punct:]]/ };{ ((c[$w]++));}
for w in ${!c[@]};{ i=${c[$w]};((m=i>m?i:m));s[$i]+=$w:;}
for((i=m;i>0;i--));{ printf "${s[i]//:/:$i
}";}
```

Save as a script file, `chmod +x`, and run:

```
$ ./countoccur This is a text and a number: 31.
a:2
and:1
number:1
text:1
31:1
is:1
This:1
$
```

Answer (score 2):

## q (50)

```
desc count each group" "vs ssr[;"[^0-9A-Za-z]";" "]
```

- ssr replaces non alphanumeric
- " "vs splits the result into a symbol list
- count each group counts creates a dict matching distinct elements of the list with the number of occurances
- desc sorts the dict by descending values

edit: fixed accidentally matching ascii 58-64 and 91-96

Comment: I've no knowledge of `q` but is the regex `[0-z]` ASCII-based?  If it is, wouldn't it also include ASCII chars 58-64?  Because those are `: ; < = > ? @`.

Comment: Great catch jimbob, thanks

Comment: You're welcome; only spotted because I found the same in C#.  Sadly, same with `[A-z]`, which matches ASCII 91-96, which are `[ \ ] ^ _ ``

Comment: ah right you are, nice little ascii lesson right there!

Comment: I just discovered `[^_\W]+` for mine, which should be *"exclude non-word characters and underscore"*, if your syntax supports the `\W` class...

Answer (score 2):

## k [71 chars]

```
f:{s:" ",x;`_k!m@k:|(!m)@<.:m:#:'=`$1_'(&~((),/:s)like"[a-zA-Z0-9]")_s}
```

Any other character except alphanumeric chars will be considered as delimiter.

#### example

```
f "This is a text and a number: 31."
a     | 2
31    | 1
number| 1
and   | 1
text  | 1
is    | 1
This  | 1
```

#### example

```
f "won't won won-won"
won| 4
t  | 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (135)

```
u=/\w+/g
for(i=s.length;i--;)for(w in a=s.match(u))u[w=a[w]]=u[w]||a.reduce(function(p,c){return p+=w==c},0)==i&&!console.log(w+":"+i)
```

Unminified:

```
u=/\w+/g;for (i=s.length;i--;)
    for(w in a=s.match(u))
        u[w=a[w]] = u[w] || 
           a.reduce(function(p,c){return p+=w==c},0)==i && !console.log(w+":"+i)
```

Loops over every possible number of matches in descending order, and outputs words with that number of occurrences. Just to be horrible.

Notes: Alert would have reduced the length some. Strictly speaking alphanumeric should be `[^\W_]`

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell (153 = 104 code + 49 import)

Pretty straight-forward, totally composed function... no argument even necessary! This is my first golf, so go easy, maybe? :)

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List
import Data.Ord
so=reverse.(sortBy$comparing snd).(map(\t@(x:_)->(x,length t))).group.sort.(map$filter isAlphaNum).words
```

Output:

```
*Main> so "This is a text and a number: 31."
[("a",2),("text",1),("number",1),("is",1),("and",1),("This",1),("31",1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

## AWK

```
awk -vRS='[^A-Za-z0-9]' '$0{c[$0]++}END{for(i in c)print c[i]"\t"i": "c[i]|"sort -nr|cut -f2-"}'
```

Does the job without gawkish extensions:

```
$ echo 'This is a text and a number: 31.' | awk -vRS='[^A-Za-z0-9]' '$0{c[$0]++}END{for(i in c)print c[i]"\t"i": "c[i]|"sort -nr|cut -f2-"}'
a: 2
This: 1
text: 1
number: 1
is: 1
and: 1
31: 1
```

If printing "count: word" instead, it would be a bit shorter but I wanted to mimic the given example output...

Answer (score 2):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 99 bytes

```
proc C s {lmap w [split [regsub -all \[^\\w|\ \] $s {}]] {dict inc D $w}
lsort -s 2 -inde 1 -de $D}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HU3NCsMgGLv3KULp1UG3267tI@ymDqyVTbBW9CsOOp/dySAkOeSHtKs1xF1jQsLpNhWQwVNwlsCjeaVjAVPOQfCnEPkrICSGFi1S4lytJlivMWPIpXNpjwSWcAWzfjUYwRoPc6n/5Vbr@sfbJjQokPkQlF@b9ce2mHjHbbz0XcEZDkrtRoBPTWSpPw)

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.X (108 - Characters)

```
print'\n'.join('{}:{}'.format(a,b)for a,b in __import__("collections").Counter(raw_input().split()).items())
```

Python 3.X (106 - Characters)

```
print('\n'.join('{}:{}'.format(a,b)for a,b in __import__("collections").Counter(input().split()).items())
```

Comment: `Separators will be anything that is not alpha-numeric` - You only split on whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3 - 76

The requirement of splitting on non-alphanumeric chars unfortunately extends the code by 19 chars. The output of the following is shown correctly. If you are not sure, add a `.most_common()` after the `.Counter(...)`.

```
i=__import__
print(i('collections').Counter(i('re').findall('\w+',input())))
```

#### In/Output

Given the input of `This is a text and a number: 31.` you get following output:

```
Counter({'a': 2, 'is': 1, 'This': 1, 'and': 1, '31': 1, 'number': 1, 'text': 1})
```

I tried it with other values like

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 2 1 5 3 4 6 8 1 3 2 4 6 1 2 8 4 3 1 3 2 5 6 5 4  2 2 4 2 1 3 6
```

to ensure, the output-order does not rely on the key's value/hash. This example produces:

```
Counter({'2': 8, '3': 6, '1': 6, '4': 6, '6': 5, '5': 4, '8': 3, '7': 1})
```

But as I said, `print(i('collections').Counter(i('re').findall('\w+',input())).most_common())` would return the results as an *definitly* ordered list of tuples.

---

### Python 3 - 57 *(if a space would be enough for splitting :P)*

```
print(__import__('collections').Counter(input().split()))
```

Comment: If you assumed the string was in some variable s, as some other answers do, you could lose 6 characters by replacing input().

Comment: @PhilH well. you are right, but I would never read that out of the requirements. sure the "string for JavaScript"-part might suggest it, but I cannot, with a clear conscience, interpret a string-variable as a valid "input". But you are right. that would shorten it even more. :P

Comment: -1. Underscore `_` should not be included in a word.

Comment: Well this depends on the definition of alpha-numeric. In Python,  "\w" is defined for accepting alpha-numeric chars. You might be correct but a with this kind of interpretation of the rules,  my solution keeps being correct. :)

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell - 137

```
import Data.List
count text=let textS=(words(text\\".-\':")) in (sortBy (\(_,n) (_,m) -> compare m n)).nub$map(\t->(t,(length.(filter(==t)))textS)) textS
```

Comment: Doesn't fulfill the condition that non-alphanumeric should be separator.

Answer (score 1):

**J, 35+?**

```
(~.(([\:]);]\:]),.@(+/"1@=))@(>@;:)
```

Doesn't fully work though. Problem is that the splitting into words ';:' monad doesn't handle non-alplanumeric characters in quite the right way. Any suggestions?

Here's how you use it:

```
(~.(([\:]);]\:]),.@(+/"1@=))@(>@;:) 'This is a text and a number: 31.'
┌───────┬─┐
│a      │2│
│This   │1│
│is     │1│
│text   │1│
│and    │1│
│number:│1│
│31.    │1│
└───────┴─┘
```

Answer (score 1):

## [LiveScript](http://livescript.net) - 74 (translation of ECMA one)

```
s.match(/[^_\W]+/g,a={})map (->-~=a[it]),keys(a)map(->[it,a[it]])sort (.1-&1.1)
```

Comment: Then it's a problem of the ECMA one :)

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure

```
(defn wc [s]
  (let [mc #(assoc % %2 (inc (get % %2 0)))]
    (sort-by #(- (val %))
             (reduce mc {} (re-seq #"\w+" (.toLowerCase s))))))
```

example:

```
(wc "hi mom hi dad hello peter hello dad hi")
;; (["hi" 3] ["hello" 2] ["dad" 2] ["peter" 1] ["mom" 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

## Smalltalk, <strike>91</strike> 78

```smalltalk
input in s

(s allRegexMatches:'\w+')asBag valuesAndCountsDo:[:c :n|(c,$:)print.n printNL]
```

input:

> pick-me-up This is a text and a number: 31.

output:

```
31:1
pick:1
text:1
me:1
number:1
up:1
is:1
a:2
and:1
This:1
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python (95):

```
a=sorted(raw_input().split(__import__("string").punctuation))
for i in set(a):print i,a.count(i)
```

Pretty straightforward, I'd say.

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 56 bytes

What, no Mathematica answer yet? This one is not quite a winner, but it's both concise *and* quite expressive:

```
f=SortBy[Tally@StringCases[#,WordCharacter..],-Last@#&]&
```

Calling `f["This is a text and a number: 31."]` yields

```
{
 {"a", 2},
 {"31", 1},
 {"and", 1},
 {"is", 1},
 {"number", 1},
 {"text", 1},
 {"This", 1}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## shell utils, also 42 characters

```
tr -sc [:alnum:] \\n|sort|uniq -c|sort -rn
```

Another approach that equals Thor's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Will never win but wanted to try anyway...

## C# (118)

```
var i = "This is a text and a number: 31.";
//The above line is not counted
Regex.Split(i,@"[\W_]").Where(w=>w!="").GroupBy(g=>g).OrderBy(o=>-o.Count()).Select(s=>new{s.Key,V=s.Count()}).Dump();
```

Ungolfed:

```
Regex.Split(i, @"[\W_]")                         //split by special chars
     .Where(w => w != "")                        //remove empty
     .GroupBy(g => g)                            //group by word
     .OrderBy(o => -o.Count())                   //order by reversed count
     .Select( s => new { s.Key, V = s.Count() }) //select value and count
     .Dump();                                    //write to screen (LinQPad)
```

Comment: @m.buettner Thanks for the tip on the epxression! :)

Comment: Actually, `\W|_` is another byte shorter. I was wondering if you could save the `Where` call if you used a slightly more advanced expression, but I can't seem to find a way to deal with a leading or trailing `""`, if the string doesn't start with an alphanumeric character.

Answer (score 1):

## J 69

Should handle corner-cases like ' - etc, at the huge cost of including all alphanumeric characters (`u:62$,65 97 48+/i.26`):

```
(>@~.,.':',.":@#/.~)(#~*@#&>)(<;._1~-.@e.&(u:62$,65 97 48+/i.26))'.',
```

Usage: just append whatever string to be counted bewteen single quotes (mind that you need to double single quotes in the string).

Example:

```
   (>@~.,.':',.":@#/.~)(#~*@#&>)(<;._1~-.@e.&(u:62$,65 97 48+/i.26))'.','This is a text and a number: 31. More-tests wouldn''t be bad'
This  :1
is    :1
a     :2
text  :1
and   :1
number:1
31    :1
More  :1
tests :1
wouldn:1
t     :1
be    :1
bad   :1
```

Answer (score 1):

**Python 2 - 61**

Assuming the input is in variable `s`, which is more realistic in real programming than user input anyway.

```
import re,collections as c
print c.Counter(re.split('\W+',s))
```

**output**

```
Counter({'a': 2, 'and': 1, '': 1, 'This': 1, 'text': 1, 'is': 1, 'number': 1, '31': 1})
```

This isn't really good output me thinks. It has an empty word and isn't readable. Here's a version with neat output (90):

**Python 2 (neat) - 90**

```
import re,collections as c
d=c.Counter(re.split('\W+',s))
for w in d:
  if w:print w+':'+`d[w]`
```

**output**

```
a:2
and:1
This:1
text:1
is:1
number:1
31:1
```

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure

```
(defn count-words [string]
  (as-> string s
        (clojure.string/replace s #"[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]" "")
        (clojure.string/split s #"\W")
        (frequencies s)
        (sort-by val s)
        (reverse s)))

(clojure.pprint/pprint (count-words "This is a text and a number: 31."))

;; => (["a" 2] ["31" 1] ["number" 1] ["and" 1] ["text" 1] ["is" 1] ["This" 1])
```

I thought I would beat markw's concision with this approach, but I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 6, <s>53</s> 39 bytes

```
{.comb(/<-[_\W]>+/).Bag.sort:{-.value}}
```

I use `.comb` to find every word matching the regexp `<-[_\W]>+`. In Perl 6, character classes are written `<[]>` instead of `[]`, and negative character classes `<-[]>` instead of `[^]`.

We then transform the list of words to a `Bag` (a set that keeps the number of occurences), and we sort said bag by their value.

Answer (score 0):

**C# (332)**

*This is my original program after excluding white spaces. Please pardon me if I did mistake in counting*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class P
{        
    static void Main(String[] A)
    {           
        Dictionary<string,int> D=new Dictionary<string,int>();
        foreach(string s in A)
        {
            if(!D.ContainsKey(s))
                D.Add(s,1);
            else D[s]+= 1;
        }
        foreach(KeyValuePair<string,int> i in D.OrderByDescending(k=>k.Value))
            Console.WriteLine(i.Key+":" + i.Value);
    }
}
```

This is program with lots of character saving after suggestions from my dear friend [jimbobmcgee](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/14754/jimbobmcgee)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class P
{
    static void Main(string[] A)
    {        
       var D = new Dictionary<string, int>();
       foreach (var v in A)
       {
          if (!D.ContainsKey(v))
            D[v] = 1;
          else D[v] += 1;
       }
     foreach (var v in D.OrderBy(k=>-k.Value))
     {
        Console.WriteLine(v.Key+": "+v.Value);
     }
   }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Assuming you are ripping out all whitespace, I make it 332: `using System;using System.Collections.Generic;using System.Linq;class P{static void Main(String[]A){Dictionary<string,int>D=new Dictionary<string,int>();foreach(string s in A){if(!D.ContainsKey(s))D.Add(s,1);else D[s]+=1;}foreach(KeyValuePair<string,int> i in D.OrderByDescending(k=>k.Value))Console.WriteLine(i.Key+":"+i.Value);}}`

Comment: Thanks. I will edit it. How can we do it without manually deleting spaces?

Comment: remove 19c if `Dictionary<string,int> D=...` becomes `var D=...`; same with `foreach(string s...` becoming (foreach(var s...` for 3c; `D.Add(s,1);` can become `D[s]=1` for a 5c saving; same with `foreach(KeyValuePair...` becoming `foreach(var...` for 21c...

Comment: What's wrong with manually deleting spaces?

Comment: 15c saving for replacing the entire `if(!D...` block with `D[s]=D.ContainsKey(s)?D[s]+1:1;`; also `D.OrderByDescending(k=>k.Value)` can become `D.OrderBy(k=>-k.Value)` for 9c.

Comment: That said, yours doesn't handle the `:` in the input, which should be treated as a separator

Comment: @jimbobmcgee Another 34 chars saved by using a `SortedList`, allowing you to remove `using System.Linq;` (-8) and swap the `foreach` with `for(int i=0;i<D.Count;i++)` (-34) but with a penalty when you use `Console.WriteLine(D.Keys[i]+":"+D.Values[i]);` (+8). Another 14 saved by getting rid of the two remaining `using` statements and just using the fully qualified names.

Comment: If you remove the `using System`, it'll complain about `String[]`, but just use the `string` keyword instead (`string[]`). You can trim off two more characters by removing the braces in the second `for`/`foreach` statement - they're not required when you have a single statement in the loop. Ah, I didn't see the `KeyValuePair` => `var` change in @jimbobmcgee's first comment - so the `for` saving with the `SortedList` is only 14 chars, not 34.

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript (ES5),  146**

```
 F=Function;a={};r="return ";b="b";x=prompt().match(/\w+/g);alert(""+x.filter(F(b,r+"!~(a[b]=~-a[b])")).map(F(b,r+"-a[b]+':'+b")).sort().reverse())
```

> =>|  This is a text and a number: 31.
>   <=|  2:a,1:text,1:number,1:is,1:and,1:This,1:31

Comment: -1. Underscore `_` should not be included in a word.

Answer (score 0):

**JAVA CODE**

```
 String s="This is a text and a number: 31";
                String[] stringArray = s.split(" ");
                final Map<String, Integer> counter = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                for (String str : stringArray)
                    counter.put(str, 1 + (counter.containsKey(str)counter.get(str): 0));
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(counter.keySet());
                Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(String x, String y) {
                        return counter.get(y) - counter.get(x);
                    }
                });
                list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
                for (String str : list) {
                    int frequency = counter.get(str);
                    System.out.println(str + ":" + frequency);
                }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 a:2
 text:1
 is:1
 31:1
 number::1
 This:1
 and:1
```

Comment: This is a code-golf question. At the very least you could remove all unnecessary spaces (like between `)` and `{`) and shorten **all** variable names to 1 character.

Comment: -1. `:` should not be part of a word

Answer (score 0):

## Python3 (244 bytes)

```
import re, collections as c, sys
t=''
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    t+=f.read()
d=c.Counter([s for s in (re.sub('[\s\W]','\n',t).split('\n')) if s])
for x in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[::-1]:
    print('{}:{}'.format(x[0],x[1]))
```

Works also with newlines, tabs etc. in the sample text.

### Output

```
> $ python3 wc.py test.txt
a:2
text:1
is:1
This:1
and:1
number:1
31:1
```

Comment: Just split along `[^_\W]+`