# Make a word cloud from a text

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output

The code should take text from standard input:

```
The definition of insanity is quoting the same phrase again and again and not expect despair.
```

The output should be a PNG file containing the [word cloud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_cloud) corresponding to that text:

[image]

The above [word cloud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_cloud) was created [using a specialized online application](http://worditout.com/word-cloud/make-a-new-one) and it filtered the word `The` and other common words (`of`, `is`, `and`, `not`, and `the`). Since this is code golf, the common words will not be filtered and I leave secondary aesthetics of the word cloud to the choice of each coder. Unlike the image exampled here, no words should be excluded, common or otherwise. The definition of a word is defined below.

In this case a word is anything alpha-numeric; numbers are not acting as separators. So, for example, `0xAF` qualifies as a word. Separators will be anything that is not alpha-numeric, including `.`(dot) and `-`(hyphen). Thus `i.e.` or `pick-me-up` would result in 2 or 3 words, respectively. Should be case sensitive - `This` and `this` would be two different words,  `'` would also be separator so `wouldn` and `t` will be 2 different words from `wouldn't`.

The tags should appear clustered but not overlapping and the font size should be directly proportional to the number of occurrences of that word in the text. The word should appear only once. Specific font color is not required in this case. Semantic association is not a requirement.

**Hint** - This other code golf could help:
[Count the words in a text and display them](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19568/count-the-words-in-a-text-and-display-them)

Comment: Please explain what you consider a *word cloud*. Also I don't understand your output definitions. Can you please clarify what you mean by *output should be printed with new line after each character*?

Comment: @Howard sorry the paragraph you mentioned was wrong I edited the question to exclude that and add more specification in order to make the requirements clear, thanks for bringing that up

Comment: The sample image doesn't seem to match the requirements. It also creates a question about how many times each word should appear in the cloud, which you don't answer anywhere.

Comment: @PeterTaylor You are right, I edited the question

Comment: This seems kinda "I need code for this, but it is off topic at SO, so I will make it a code golf instead."

Comment: @TimSeguine I don't think code-golf submissions have any kind of reusability...

Comment: @WanderNauta I think that depends on your definition of usable. Desperate times call for desperate measures. Anyway, I only meant it half serious. :)

Comment: @TimSeguine Legitimate concern, but why would I need it when there are scores of free apps to do that.

Comment: Personally I can't image any valid use of such PNG. Usually word clouds need to be interactive.

Comment: Your word cloud creator also seems to have filtered `of`, `is`, `and`, `not`, and `the`.

Comment: Read from stdin? Expot a PNG? How am I supposed to do this in Emacs?? :)

Comment: I think getting rid of the common words would make an excellent bonus, personally.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Output example]

## Python 3, <strike>363</strike> <strike>308</strike> <strike>293</strike> 274 characters

```py
import os,sys,re,collections as C
c=C.Counter()
n=sys.argv[1]
o="graph d{"
for w in re.findall("\w*",open(n).read()):c[w]+=1
for w,x in c.most_common(75)[1:]:o+="%s[fontsize=%s,shape=none];"%(w,x/5)
open(n+'.dot','w').write(o+"}")
os.system("fdp -Tpng %s.dot>%s.png"%(n,n))
```

Call it like this: `python cloud.py file.txt`. The script uses Graphviz's `fdp` force-directed graph generator to generate the image (it will spit out a GraphViz file to file.txt.dot and a PNG image file to file.txt.png). *This means you'll need to have Graphviz installed.*

The image above is the cloud it makes of Shakespeare's Hamlet - you can tell, since it contains "To be or not to be". There's also some delightful nonsense to be found:

> It is, to You and I, the Ham of <sup>Not that<sup>O lord have us, what now...</sup></sup>

Comment: You may need to tweak the constant `/5` in the second-to-last line depending on how large your text is. 5 works well for Hamlet-sized texts, 500 for Bible-length input and so on.

Answer (score 5):

### JAVASCRIPT 473

```
var wordCloud=function(e){var t=e.split(/[\s-.,;]+/);var n={},r;for(r in t){var i=t[r];n[i]=n[i]+1||1}var s=document;var o=s.createElement("canvas");o.width=600;o.height=400;o.style.display="none";s.body.appendChild(o);var u=o.getContext("2d");var a=0,f=50;for(var i in n){u.font=n[i]*50+"px monospace";u.fillText(i,a,f+n[i]*5);a+=i.length*n[i]*50;if(a>o.width*.6){a=0;f+=n[i]*5+100}}var l=o.toDataURL("image/png");var c=s.createElement("img");c.src=l;s.body.appendChild(c)}
```

#### [Ungolfed demo](http://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/Lzmga/)

```
wordCloud("string;abc,test-omg shouldn't test omg lalala. s2 s2 s2")
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this produces a PNG file?

Comment: Now it does !!!

Comment: Cool. (As possible, please update the live demo too.)

Comment: already did! thx @manawork

Comment: Regarding the golfing, this shortened version seems to do it in 360 characters: http://pastebin.com/C4dpYLP8

Comment: ...296 characters: http://pastebin.com/5BUPavYH

Comment: just realized there's no need to append/hide the canvas

Comment: I'm also going to golf this even more into 405 bytes. [Try it here!](http://codepen.io/PeanutSE/pen/RRBkkk)